# Стоит ли связывать диплом с программированием android?

Tags: java, android

Только начал осваивать джаву, а приложение нужно будет уже полностью написать и оформить через 4 месяца. И главная проблема - не могу решить что именно писать, потому что пока не понимаю, что смогу осилить. Поэтому подкиньте пару идей, пожалуйста. Специальность: инфокоммуникационные технологии и системы связи.

Comment: Какой стек технологий вы знаете?

Comment: Знания почти нулевые, пока что только основы ООП и море энтузиазма. Для этого и создавалась тема, нужна идея для которой не потребуется "фулл стак" для реализации. Ну и чтобы была интересна преподавателям (возможно связанная с ВУЗом)

Comment: Так и не понял бакалавр или магистр, но можно за тему взять тот же заезженный месенджер для андроид, информации как исходников хватает, но нужно будет и серверную часть делать (оформлять). Для научки в тот же месенджер пихают шифрование.

Answer (score 4):

> Только начал осваивать джаву, а приложение нужно будет уже полностью написать и оформить через 4 месяца.

Я бы не рекомендовал с таким бекграундом (за исключением колосального опыта в разработке) брать проект, настолько ограниченный по времени

> И главная проблема - не могу решить что именно писать, потому что пока не понимаю, что смогу осилить.

Посоветуйся со своим преподователем программирования. Он явно лучше нас знает твои знания, способности и возможности

Comment: Неужели вообще ничего не можете посоветовать? А преподаватель, один плечи пожимает, говорит, как-то раз студент написал приложение с расписанием занятий - зашло. У другого смысла спрашивать нет, на этом список и заканчивается.

Comment: @ИванРепенцев чтоб давать какие-то советы, нужно понимать, что вы знаете/умеете. Как я уже сказал, если вы только начали изучать java - я бы не советовал вам связываться с Андроидом. Больше никаких сведений, на основании которых можно было бы что-то посоветовать, у меня нет. Как вариант, попробуйте более подробно расписать ваши знания/умения

Comment: Достаточно хорошо работать в фотошопе, так что с оформлением чего-то проблем думаю не будет. Занимался какое-то время навигацией вконтакте (что-то вроде лэндинг-страниц, только для групп и пабликов,  ну и их настройкой через wiki-разметку) . На среднем уровне знаю английский, хорошо рисую. Но вряд ли из этого что-то мне сильно пригодится под мои задачи

Comment: @ИванРепенцев - _фотошоп_, _рисую_ - так может зря вы в программирование пошли? Учились бы на дизигнера.

Comment: Душа к этому, к сожалению, не лежит, делалось это по необходимости заработка. И к программированию я начал "идти" только сейчас :) Не хочу делать из темы холивар, простите.

Comment: @ИванРепенцев как итог, знания в программировании у вас достаточно скромные. Я бы рекомендовал выбрать что нибудь по-проще. Сайтик какой, или что-то вроде того

Answer (score 2):

Если только что начал осваивать Java то 4 месяца не так много.

Могу посоветовать что можно сделать быстро(относительно)

1 Приложение погоды(в интернете полно уроков), можно потом дополнять: определение местоположения, поиск, карту и т.д. и т.п.

2 TODO list(Заметки), с напоминаем и push notification

3 Какой нибудь будильник

4 Можно было бы создать чат, но на это нужно больше времени (так как ты начал только сейчас осваивать Java)

Answer (score 0):

Идея, несомненно, хорошая. И её можно использовать на благо учебного заведения. Например, когда учился в колледже сделал сайт по математике с формулами, практическими и другими материалами под конкретного преподавателя и программу курса. Другой студент из сайта сделал мобильное приложение с оффлайн доступом. Преподаватели, конечно же, радовались :)

Поэтому, отвечая на ваш вопрос:

- Приложение по какому-либо предмету с материалами
- Приложение для деканата о прогулах и т.д.
- Новостное приложение для университета
- Приложение с расписаниями

Comment: Спасибо большое, хоть кто-то относится с пониманием. А приложение о прогулах можно ли как-то интересно реализовать? Думаете на практике применяться будет? Может электронный журнал сделать, или слишком простая тема для диплома... У нас уже есть приложение с расписанием, со встроенной новостной лентой, не хочется повторяться, а с материалами наверное будет слишком банальным

Comment: Вы хотите обрести бессмертие в вашем окружении!? :) Ваши сокурсники и не только обязательно оценят приложение о прогулах :) это что то в стиле Павлика Морозова 2ххх годов :)

Comment: Как показывает практика все ваши дипломные работы с корявыми приложениями, падающими сайтами, десктоп-аппами с кучей эксепшенов в здравом уме никто не будет юзать. Диск с приложением будет сложен на полку и успешно позабыт. Поэтому не надо строить иллюзий что вы напишете крутяцкое приложение. Нет, такого не будет.

Comment: Мне нужно лишь, чтобы преподаватели оценили идею больше, чем реализацию. Например, у нас есть сайт, где выкладывают оценки, учебную программу и всё такое. Сложно ли будет сделать к нему мобильную версию?

Comment: @ИванРепенцев, вот мобильное приложение на базе сайта, это не очень сложно. Полно доступных примеров и готовых реализаций, это будет наверное самый удачный выбор. А если у сайта ещё и внешние АПИ есть.. тогда вам просто повезло